# Using setInterval() with XMLHttpRequest results in null or { <anonymous> }

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, es6-promise, setinterval

I'm fairly new to learning JavaScript, so I very well may be missing an obvious piece here. I'm trying to have an XMLHttpRequest run periodically (when told to start) to pull the most up-to-date data into my array. When I run this code below, I get the console.log once, but it doesn't execute again the next time around.

I can call "makeAPIGet(url)" twice in my code, but when I use setInterval() it won't execute teh seoncd time.  Any advise on what I'm missing or what to do here? thank!

EDIT: I've narrowed down what is causing the issue; when the function is run the second time, the argument is set to undefined. Is there a way for the argument to remain, other than making a global argument?

```
const promise = require('promise');
const XMLHttpRequest = require('XMLHttpRequest').XMLHttpRequest;

function makeAPIGet(url) {
  return new promise(function(resolve,reject) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === this.DONE && this.status === 200) {
        let result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
        console.log(result);
        resolve();
      };
    });

    xhr.open("GET",url);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("//");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("//");
    xhr.send();

  });
};

setInterval(makeAPIGet,1000),
makeAPIGet('//')
```

*note: I am sending a url and setting appropriate headers, they are removed for the purpose of this post*

this returns:
{my desired result}

then nothing. the code doesn't end, it just sits there until I force stop the execution.

Comment: `setInterval(makeAPIGet,1000)`, <= you're not passing in a url.

Comment: `setInterval(() => makeAPIGet('//'),1000),`

Comment: "note: I am sending a url and setting appropriate headers, they are removed for the purpose of this post"

Comment: Taplar's comment is correect. You are passing the function to `setInterval` but how should it know with which arguments to call it? Instead you have to pass a function that calls `makeAPIGet` with the right arguments.

Comment: I understand now, thank you